# Graph splitting via an algorithm and proof of properties

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof

Given the following function:

```
function split(G)
    if (all vertices of G have even degree) then
        return (V (G), ∅)
    else  
        Let a ∈ V be a vertex of odd degree;
        S ← NG(a); 
        G ← G − a;
        for ((∀)u, v ∈ S, u != v) do
            if (uv ∈ E(G)) then 
                E(G) ← E(G) − uv; 
            else 
                E(G) ← E(G) ∪ uv;
        (W1, W2) ← split(G);
        if (|W1 ∩ S| % 2 = 0) then 
            V1 ← W1 ∪ {a}; 
            V2 ← W2;
        else 
            V2 ← W2 ∪ {a}; 
            V1 ← W1;
return (V1, V2)
```

I have to show that V1∩V2 = ∅, V1∪V2 = V(G) and the subgraphs of G obtained from V1 and V2 have an even degree on all vertices.

Now, based on the function it is obvious that the properties stated above hold true, but I am stumped as to how exactly should I go about proving them and by what general rule or criteria the split function splits the graph(I have no problem following the algorithm but the "big picture" escapes me).

EDIT: NG(a) Is the set of a's neighbours.

Comment: Try running the algorithm on a few concrete examples.

Comment: A proof is a convincing argument that the algorithm does what it's supposed to. Produce such an argument.

Comment: If it is "obvious" that the properties stated above hold, then the reason this is obvious will constitute a proof.

Comment: You'll probably need some kind of inductive argument (as there is recursion).

Comment: What is "S ← NG(a)"?  If it sets `S` to a New Graph containing just the vertex `a`, then the subsequent `for` will never execute as there are no two distinct vertices `u`, `v` in `S`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you the schema of the proof. You'll have to fill in the blanks on your own. The idea is to prove by induction the following property $P(n)$:

> On a graph $G$ having $n$ vertices, the function $\mathrm{split}(G)$ terminates and returns a partition $V_1,V_2$ of the vertex set of $V$ such that in the subgraphs of $G$ induced by $V_1$ and $V_2$, all vertices have even degree.

First you have to prove the base case $P(1)$. That's quite easy.

Now, for every $n$ you have to prove that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$. To do this, you analyze what happens when $\mathrm{split}$ is run on a graph $G$ having $n+1$ vertices. There are two cases: if all degrees in $G$ are even then it is easy to see that $\mathrm{split}(G)$ terminates with an appropriate partition. Otherwise, $\mathrm{split}$ creates a graph $G'$ on $n$ vertices and runs itself on $G'$. Since $G'$ has $n$ vertices, the induction hypothesis implies that $\mathrm{split}(G')$ with a partition $V'_1,V'_2$ of the vertex set of $G'$ such that the subgraphs of $G'$ induced by $V'_1,V'_2$ have only even degrees. The procedure $\mathrm{split}$ uses $V'_1,V'_2$ to create a partition $V_1,V_2$ of the graph $G$. It thus clearly terminates. To finish the proof, you have to show that the subgraphs of $G$ induced by $V_1,V_2$ have all even degrees.

This is the structure of the proof. All you have to do now is to fill in the blanks.